# Can I pass a parameter to ISessionFactory in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am very new (i.e. an hour or so) to NHibernate.  I've followed a tutorial which gave me the following class:

```
public class ContactNHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                var configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.Configure();
                configuration.AddAssembly(typeof (CRMData.Objects.Contact).Assembly);
                _sessionFactory = configuration.Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

In extending my application, I now have another class for a different object.  I'm trying to rewrite the above class so that I can pass in the assembly type as a parameter and return the _sessionFactory.  So, for example, I would have a variable passed in to the method called assembly.  The code would then be:

```
public class GenericNHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory(System.Reflection.Assembly assembly)
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                var configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.Configure();
                configuration.AddAssembly(assembly);
                _sessionFactory = configuration.Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }
}
```

This is giving the error 'Cannot resolve symbol 'get'' - presumably because I cannot pass any parameters in this way.

I am probably missing something very simple - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to make any changes if your other class is in the same assembly as CRMData.Objects.Contact.

But if you want to pass in a parameter you need to convert the SessionFactory property to a method or create a constructor that accepts the parameter.

```
private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory(System.Reflection.Assembly assembly)
{
    if (_sessionFactory == null)
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.Configure();
        configuration.AddAssembly(assembly);
        _sessionFactory = configuration.Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    return _sessionFactory;
}
```

Comment: That worked - I'm a little 'green' when it comes to programming, so whilst this worked I've little idea as to why! Many thanks.

Comment: My only issue with this code is the "assembly" parameter will not be taken into the consideration if you call the SessionFactory method multiple times.

Comment: @Dmitry - can you expand on that? Is this something to do with the "static" qualifier? I haven't yet worked out what static does.

Comment: Here is a scenario. At first you run the method with an assembly instance passed in as a parameter. The second time you run the method with a different assembly instance passed in. You would expect the session factory to use the second assembly instance but it would still use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

we dont have parameter properties in C# other than indexers.That is the reason you are getting the error.change your code to use a method.

But i still dont understand why you need to pass an assembly to the method.

Comment: I'm trying to create a generic method that saves me having to create a whole new class every time I want to create a new ISessionFactory based on a different assembly (CRMData.Objects.Contact, CRMData.Objects.Account, CRMData.Objects.Staff, CRMData.Objects.etc...)